# Why is this program meant to return dollars, quarters and dimes not doing the math correctly?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I'm trying to write a program that will return change for a specific integer of cents. So for example 92 cents would return: 0 dollars, 3 quarters, 1 dime, 1 nickel and 2 pennies.

This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    // 1. ask user to enter an integer: total cents
    cout << "Hi! Enter an integer representing the total number of cents pls: " << endl;
    
    int user_num{};
    
    // 2. save in std cin
    cin >> user_num;
    
    // 3. check dollars
    int dollars{};
    int add_to_dollars{};
    
    if ( user_num >= 100 ) {             // eg. user_num is 240 
        // calculate amount to add to dollars variable
        add_to_dollars = user_num / 100;              // 240 / 100 = 2.4 keep the 2
        dollars = dollars + add_to_dollars;
        
        // what is the total user_num once we subtract the dollars?  eg. 240 - 200 = 40
        user_num = user_num % 100;              // 240 % 100 = 40
    }
    
    // 4. check quarters
    int quarters{};
    int add_to_quarters{};
    
    if ( user_num >= 25 ) {      // eg. 40
        // how much do we add to quarters variable?
        add_to_quarters = user_numd/25;            //  40 / 25 = 1.6
        quarters = quarters + add_to_quarters;     // add the 1 ^ 
        
        // subtract this to total cents     eg. subtract 25
        user_num = user_num % 25;  
    }
    
    // 5. check dimes
    int dimes{};
    int add_to_dimes{};
    
    if ( user_num >= 10 ) {      
        add_to_dimes = user_num / 10;            
        quarters = quarters + add_to_dimes;     
        user_num = user_num % 10;  
    }

    // 6. check nickels
    int nickels{};
    int add_to_nickels{};
    
    if ( user_num >= 5 ) {      
        add_to_nickels = user_num / 5;            
        quarters = quarters + add_to_nickels;     
        user_num = user_num % 5;  
    }
    
    // 7. check pennies
    int pennies{};
    int add_to_pennies{};
    
    if ( user_num >= 1 ) {      
        add_to_pennies = user_num / 1;            
        quarters = quarters + add_to_pennies;     
        user_num = user_num % 1;  
    }
    
    // 8. return total info of each variable
    cout << "You can provide change for this change as follows: " << endl;
    cout << "dollars: " << dollars << endl;
    cout << "quarters: " << quarters << endl;
    cout << "dimes: " << dimes << endl;
    cout << "nickels: " << nickels << endl;
    cout << "pennies: " << pennies << endl;

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, the answer to for example, 92 cents gives me 7 quarters, when it should be saying 3 quarters. Is the logic inherently wrong of am I writing the C++ code incorrectly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have many comments that are incorrect or at least confusing: `//  40 / 25 = 1.6` remember that  `40/25` in c++ is 1 because 40 and 25 are both integers.

Comment: My advice to you is to obtain a debugger and step through the calculations from the top 1 line at a time looking at the variables before and after each step you take in the debugger.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: The code can be greatly simplified. For example, computing the number of dollars can be reduced to two lines: `int dollars = user_num / 100;` and `user_num %= 100`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you have some copy-paste errors:

```
quarters = quarters + add_to_dimes; 
// ...
quarters = quarters + add_to_nickels;
// ...
quarters = quarters + add_to_pennies;
```

These should use `dimes`, `nickels`, and `pennies` respectively instead of `quarters`.

To prevent this sort of error in the future, if you ever find yourself copy-pasting code, consider instead refactoring that code into a function.  For example, in this case you could have a single function like `int calculate_partial_change(int total_cents, int coin_denomination)` that deals with a single type of coin at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( user_num >= 10 ) {      
    add_to_dimes = user_num / 10;            
    quarters = quarters + add_to_dimes;   // <-- HERE  
    user_num = user_num % 10;  
}
```

This piece should be adding to dimes instead of quarters, same with your nickels and pennies sections below.

Consider breaking this logic into a separate function instead of copy-pasting it 6 times.